# Extract specific part of URL from string

Tags: php, regex, html-content-extraction

I need to extract only parts of a URL with PHP but I am struggling to the set point where the extraction should stop. I used a regex to extract the entire URL from a longer string like this:

```
$regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $href, $matches);
```

The result is the following string:

```
http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=a4rbU8agB-zY0QWS_IGYDw&amp;ved=0CFEQFjAL&amp;usg=AFQjCNGU4FMUPB2ZuVM45OoqQ39rJbfveg
```

Now I want to extract only this bit *http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/*. I basically need to get rid off everything starting at *`&amp`* onwards.

Anyone an idea how to achieve this? Do I need to run another regex or can I add it to the initial one?

Comment: I think I am going with Avinash Raj's solution below. Works well for me. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would get ridoff everything after the string `&amp`. Your php code would be,

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('~&amp.*$~', '', 'http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=a4rbU8agB-zY0QWS_IGYDw&amp;ved=0CFEQFjAL&amp;usg=AFQjCNGU4FMUPB2ZuVM45OoqQ39rJbfveg');
?> //=> http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/
```

**Explanation:**

- `&amp` Matches the string `&amp`.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `$` End of the line.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you abandon regex and let PHP's own parse_url function do this for you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$my_url = $parsed['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed['hostname'] . $parsed['path'];
```

to get the substring of the path up to the &amp, try:

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$my_url = $parsed['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed['hostname'] . substr($parsed['path'], 0, strpos($parsed['path'],'&amp'));
```

Comment: This is interesting but the path will still contain the part after &amp so it doesn't really solve my initial problem.

Comment: updated the answer for you, i think that should do what you need